# Folksonomy and people/group field

Tags: 2013, office-365, managed-metadata, people-picker, enterprise-keywords

I need to do something that have:
  - Person or Group field functionality (type ahead)
  - Tagging functionality (adding tags or selecting the existing ones)
Is there a solution out there that I can use in order to achieve this?
And I need it to work in O365 as well

Answer (score 1):

You can create Site Columns that have these properties: *Person or Group* and *Metadata Keyword* where users are allowed add keywords that doesn't exist.

These site columns can be added to a Content Type which may be a Docement or a Page or anything else. Navigate to Site Settings and find the links you need in the group Web Design Galleries.

Comment: Yes, but can i have both functionalities in just one field( site column)?

Comment: @yngrdyn No since they are different data types...